# SQL Server - .mdf file reading problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey everyone,
I am trying to read an mdf file alone. How can I read it from inside Visual Studio 2008? My point here is reading the file without defining a database. 
I've tried both "Add connection > SQL Server Compact" and "Add connection > SQL Server Database".

Comment: An .MDF file is part of a SQL Server database - you should use the intended application **exclusively** - SQL Server itself - to manipulate that file. Don't go fiddling around with the file yourself....

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can do this.  You will have to Attach Database in SQL Server to view details.

Comment: No probs. Please tick my answer if you decided this was the solution